# How to I model corresponding features in caret

Tags: r, modeling, prediction, caret

I am trying to build a binary-outcome prediction model wherein the features correspond to each outcome, for example my headers might be:

```
PersonA_Height, PersonA_Weight, PersonB_Height, PersonB_Weight, Outcome
```

So far the models I have used from R's caret have been flawed in one serious respect: The probability predictions I get are not the same when I switch the inputs, for example:

```
|A_height   |A_weight   |B_height   |B_weight   |Probabilty A |Probabilty B|
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-------------|------------|
|183        |92         |160        |105        | 55%         | 45%        |
|160        |105        |183        |9          | 40%         | 60%        |
```

In the above table, the two inputs to be predicted are the same, I have just switched A and B.  I would expect that the probability value would be the same whether or not I put A first of B first, however with the models I have created already in R the predictions are not the same when I switch the order of the features.

Note that in my training data I took care to repeat each entry twice, with A first and B first, to make sure that there was no bias in the training data to indicate that the outcome is usually whoever happens to be in the first two columns.

My question(s):

1. I assume this is a common problem which I do not have the vocabulary to describe, what is the correct way to verbally describe the prediction scenario I describe above.
2. Is it possible to create a model that takes into account the fact that the features in the data correspond to one another such that the outcome should be the same if you switch the values?
3. Can someone provide an example, or reference of how I would proceed with this kind of model with caret

**Edit:**  I have been able to get somewhat consistient results with `glmnet`, the total probabilitites now sum to around 1.05.. I'll continue using glmnet, but I still want to know how to describe this problem in general.

Comment: You want that your model will have the property that the prediction based on a (height, weight) pair will be indifferent to the rest of the features and its position, Am I right? If so, why not working with just such pairs? Besides, what are the probabilities that you measure and how are they related to the features?

Comment: @DanLevin I want the prediction to be the same regardless of whether person A is in the first two columns or in the second.  That is to say if I ask the question "What is the probability that A will win against B" and the answer is 0.6, I expect that if I then ask "What is the probability that B will win against A" the answer will be 0.4

Comment: I see. So the result is not indifferent of the other parameters. Do you get the probabilities by aggregations on labeled set? If so, a common method to make the classifier is to simulate data that respect the invariance. For example, in image classification you can scale and rotate the original images and use the same label.

Comment: I don't know what "aggregations on labeled set" means

Comment: A different method that you can use is trying to predict a score per player. The higher the score of a player, to more likely he will win. Actually, you can try the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_rating_system which seems to have the same goal as yours.

Comment: You wrote that you have the outcome in the headers. You can treat the problem as a supervised learning problem with the outcome as the concept.   If you will use a classifier that outputs confidence, you can use it as the probability.

Comment: By the way, you would also like to have the property that probability A + probability B equal to 1 for all cases, right?

Comment: Exactly that's the problem.. when I reverse the inputs the probabilities don't sum to one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53611/discussion-between-dan-levin-and-jsj).